# Java relative path in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, io, filereader

I am developing a NetBeans module where I have a Java package called `test`and another package called `test.templates`. I want to read a text file which is in the `test.templates` package from a Java file in the test package. I tried in several ways, but it gives a `FileNotFoundException` exception:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("templates/test.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/test/templates/test.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/test/templates/test.txt"));
```

But none of these worked.. I want to use the relative path, not the absolute path. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`.

Example on java2s.com:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Loadresourcefilerelativetotheclasslocation.htm

Answer (score 3):

You should note somethings about relative path (Netbeans):

+ File: Default is project folder, means outside of `src` folder.
If you save to `test.txt`, it will generate: `project/test.txt`.
If you save to `data/test.txt`, ... `project/data/test.txt`
So if you want to load file, you just do it conversely. Like this, you should put your files in project/data/filename.txt. Then when code, you get path: `data/filename.txt`.

+ ImageIcon: I will share later if can.
+ Image(SplashScreen): I will share later.

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer :v

Answer (score 1):

`getResource()` returns a URL, so to extract the filename, you can try calling `getFile()`.

The filepath you pass to getResource will be based on your netbeans package. Use a leading slash to denote the root of the classpath.

Example:

```
getResource(/db_files/table.csv).getFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getResource("/test/templates/test.txt").toString().substring(6)));
}
catch(Exception ee)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ee);   
}
```